# Create an array in Numpy using conditions on another array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array named `default` with 3 dimensions *(n_sim, t_horizon, n_loans)* whose individual cell *(i,j,k)* represents if a the *loan k* is defaulted [or not] in *time j* for the *simulation i*.

```
default = np.array([[[False, False],
        [ True, False],
        [False, False],
        [False, False],
        [False, False],
        [False, False]],

       [[False, False],
        [ True, False],
        [False, True],
        [False, False],
        [False, False],
        [False, False]]])
```

Now I would like to create an array that is *1* when the loan is performing and *0* since it has defaulted on:

```
surv = np.array([[[1, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1]],

       [[1, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0]]])
```

How can I do it efficiently?

I was trying to create an array of index mapping the first default in this way:

```
np.where(np.argmax(default > 0,axis=1) > 0, np.argmax(default > 0,axis=1) , t_horizon-1)
```

but I don't know how to apply this map then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flip your mask and compute the running minimum in time:

```
np.minimum.accumulate(default, axis=1)
```

The result is boolean, which will have most of the same properties as the integer you show in the question. If you still need integers, tack on one of the following at the end:

```
.astype(int)
```

OR

```
.view('uint8')
```

Comment: This is a relly nice one! So `surv=np.minimum.accumulate(np.logical_not(default), axis=1).astype(int)` gives the exact answer.

Comment: @Franciska. Added a note at the end. Unless you specifically need an integer, there's no reason to copy the data at the end

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to match this to OPs expected output

Comment: @MadPhysicist wow that's super nice way!

Answer (score 1):

A slightly clunky way to do things is to first reshape the array and loop over the last axis, for example, you could do:

```py
default = np.array(
    [
        [[False, False],
         [ True, False],
         [False, False],
         [False, False],
         [False, False],
         [False, False]],
        [[False, False],
         [ True, False],
         [False, True],
         [False, False],
         [False, False],
         [False, False]]
    ]
)

shape = default.shape

# array to hold ones and zeros
newdefaulted = np.ones(shape)

# move time axis to the last axis and reshape
default = np.reshape(
    np.moveaxis(default, 1, -1),
    (shape[0] * shape[-1], shape[1])
)

newdefaulted = np.reshape(
    np.moveaxis(newdefaulted, 1, -1),
    (shape[0] * shape[-1], shape[1])
)

for row1, row2 in zip(default, newdefaulted):
    w = np.argwhere(row1)
    if len(w) > 0:
        row2[w[0,0]:] = 0

# reshape newdefaulted
newdefaulted = np.moveaxis(
    np.reshape(newdefaulted, (shape[0], shape[-1], shape[1])),
    -1,
    1,
)
```

I'm sure there is a far neater and more concise way to do this.

Comment: There's a much more concise way

Comment: Indeed I was looking for a concise way but thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

Given your default array you can do this, but unfortunately this also has a loop:

```
surv=np.copy(default)
tr=np.stack(np.where(default==True),axis=1)
for index in tr:
    a,b,c=index
    surv[a,b:,c]=True
surv=np.logical_not(surv).astype(int)
```

---

```
[[[1 1]
  [0 1]
  [0 1]
  [0 1]
  [0 1]
  [0 1]]

 [[1 1]
  [0 1]
  [0 0]
  [0 0]
  [0 0]
  [0 0]]]
```